# linked comboboxes with one store in Extjs 4.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4, store

I have 2 comboboxes. The first selects a category, the second selects the sub category. Both categories are stored in one store with fields: id, parentId, label. Filtering the store isn't working since both comboboxes are bound to the same store.

How can I link the comboboxes? How can I filter the list of the second combobox?

Comment: is your store's data inline or loaded from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referring to the same store use Ext.create() to create a new instance of the same store for the second combo box. Use select or change listeners on comboboxes to trigger filtering from one to the other.

EDIT:
 Here is an example of such a beast :) http://extjs.wima.co.uk/example/1 
This is not mine but sounds exactly what you are doing. Please note the way the stores are setup for each combo box. The first Combo CREATES a new store with the new operator - although this is not the best practice, it will work. The best practice is just to use Ext.create(..).

The second Combo refers to an existing store. In your case since you are reusing the same store definition you want to use Ext.create(...)  on both Combos.

For more reference on best practices of class system read this guide: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/class_system

Comment: how can you create a new store inside a mvc model and assign it directly to the combobox?

Comment: the example is not working, but it's going kind of into the right direction. It is still using two different stores (countrie and city). I configure my store inside the mvc application structure in app/store/categories using the Ext.define: "Ext.define('app.store.categories', {extend: 'Ext.data.Store',...". Inside my first combobox I just say store: categories. Thats it, done and working. However for the second combobox I need to duplicate this store. I tried couple of thing, but I'm not sure how to get a new instance of the app.store.categories?

Comment: Did you read my answer? Use  Ext.create() to "create" a new store instance. If you just reference it by store name it will return you a reference to the shared instance.

Comment: How can I create a copy of a existing defined model? I'm to stupid for it right now.

Answer (score 1):

friend.....try **`filter`** on the store.