# Can different combos use a same store with different params?

Tags: combobox, extjs4, store, parameters

In a form, I have two combos, one is named "sales", the other is named "business".
I want Both of them get data from a store "Users" but get different options to be selected.

If I set the two combos with the same "store" property

> store: 'Users'

and use "beforeselect" event to pass different params to the store, then when the store changes, it will effect the two combos at the same time.

How can I do this? Two stores?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense from a design point of view. Why would a Users store have both sales and business records in it? It should have user records. Are you implying associations?

Comment: It's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445340/linked-comboboxes-with-one-store-in-extjs-4-0